# Refresh tableView \ View

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have tab bar application and when i press on one of the tabs the ViewDidLoad called
now if i moving to another tab and then return to the previous one the VewDidLoad didnt call
how can i know that this window load again?

and also how can i refresh a view? for example a viewtable that i made logic changes and want to refresh the new data.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `viewDidLoad` method will just called once. 
The method you want is `viewWillAppear`, you can override that one.

To refresh a tableview you could use `[tableview reloadData]`

Comment: so if i will override the method viewWillAppear with [self.tableview relaodData] then the view will draw itself with the new data?

Comment: method is actually [tableview reloadData] typo in post above